# Spring mvc : Saving a Java List in PostgreSQL with Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am working on a Spring-MVC project where I am using Hibernate for persistence. In one of the model classes I have a List which I want to persist. I am facing the problem as I don't know which dataType to use in PostgreSQL and do I need instruct hibernate in some way or other that I am trying to persist a List. Performance requirements are not that much of a problem on this list, as it does not get that much action. I am posting some code for reference, kindly let me know. Thanks a lot :

GroupAccount model class :

```
@Entity
@Table(name="groupaccount")
public class GroupAccount {

 @Column(name = "blacklist")
    private List<String> blacklist;
  public List<String> getBlacklist() {
        return blacklist;
    }

    public void setBlacklist(List<String> blacklist) {
        this.blacklist = blacklist;
    }
}
```

I would sometimes require to update the values of the blacklist, so I have a method in DAO which updates the groupAccount, I am pasting it below.

GroupAccountDAOImpl edit function :

```
 @Override
    public void editGroupAccount(GroupAccount groupAccount) {
        session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
       GroupAccount groupAccount1 = (GroupAccount)session.get(GroupAccount.class,groupAccount.getGroupId());
        if(!(groupAccount1==null)){
            groupAccount.setOwnedcanvas(groupAccount1.getOwnedcanvas());
            groupAccount.setGroupMembersSet(groupAccount1.getGroupMembersSet());
            session.merge(groupAccount);
            session.flush();
        }
    }
```

One use-case for adding users in blacklist :

```
List<String> blackListUsers;
blackListUsers = groupAccount.getBlacklist();
blackListUsers.add(memberForBlackListing.getMemberUsername());
groupAccount.setBlacklist(blackListUsers);
this.groupAccountService.editGroupAccount(groupAccount);
removeAllMemberships(memberId);
return true;
```

Any help would be nice. Thanks a lot. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't map `List<String>` to a single column. For these cases, `@ElementCollection` is used

```
@ElementCollection
@CollectionTable(name="blacklist", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="group_account_id")
@Column(name = "name")
private List<String> blacklist;
```

This requires a database table named `blacklist` with columns `name` and `group_account_id` (which will be used as a foreign key to `group_account` table). Of course, table and column names are customizable.

Comment: Ok. Thanks a lot, but is there some other type I can use, like an array which I can use for the above mentioned use-case. I just need to check if an email-address exists in the blacklist and add an Email, but in same database table. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You can use simple `String` field, and keep the list as comma separated values (CSV). Requires a little pack-unpack code, but it's the simplest solution.

Comment: I agree. I will try with that. Thanks a lot.